# How to remove last 3 digits of an integer?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, integer

I have a column like this :

| number_of_people |
| --- |
| 12345 |
| 12325 |
| 156890 |
| 126789 |
| 23903114 |
| 12988394 |

And I have been told last three digits are incorrect, so I need to remove them my query. Is there a clause I can use (I don't need to update the table). What I desired:

| number_of_people |
| --- |
| 12 |
| 12 |
| 156 |
| 126 |
| 23903 |
| 12988 |

I tried  `SELECT LEFT([number_of_people], LEN([number_of_people]) - 3) EditedColumn from HR_table limit 15;` but `LEFT` only works for string.

Answer (score 4):

Simply dividing by 1000 should work here:

```sql
SELECT number_of_people / 1000 AS number_of_people
FROM yourTable;
```

If the `number_of_people` then you should probably use an explicit cast here:

```sql
SELECT CAST(number_of_people AS INTEGER) / 1000 AS number_of_people
FROM yourTable;
```